# Cannot find configuration VisualVM in GGTS

Tags: grails, profiling, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, jvisualvm, ggts

Is there a way to use VisualVM when running a Grails application in Groovy-Grails Tool Suite? I have already installed VisualVM Eclipse plugin but cannot find where to configure this.

Answer (score 0):

The VisualVM plugin for Eclipse integrates with Eclipse (and STS/GGTS) for specific launcher only (Java Application, JUnit, Eclipse Application, etc.), as you can see from the preferences when going to "Run/Debug -> Launching -> Default Launchers". That means there is no direct integration into the Groovy launchers, unfortunately.

But you should be able to connect to a running Groovy app from the VisualVM app once the Groovy app is running. Not as convenient as the Eclipse plugin, but maybe a workaround.